# how to fix launch screen logo width?

Tags: android, nativescript

In the following code, how can I set the launch screen logo width to `72%` in android?

**Code**

```
<item android:drawable="@color/ns_theme"></item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no width and height parameters for bitmap, you can set bitmap size using gravity and item width/height.

```
<item
     android:width="230dp"
     android:height="70dp">
     <bitmap
         android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
         android:src="@drawable/screen" />
</item>
```

You can set item width and height and scale bitmap inside of it using gravity.

WARNING:

As already mentioned in comments, this method ONLY works with API level 23 (Android 6.0) and up.

Comment: can't we define it in percentage for <bitmap
         android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
         android:src="@drawable/screen" />

Comment: for that you need to write code in java means activity

Comment: Thanks Vishal Sojitra

Comment: can we add margin to the logo like this ? <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/sennheiser_logo" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" android:layout_marginRight="50dp" android:paddingLeft="50dp" android:paddingRight="50dp"/>

Comment: I need to set padding or margin 50px for the bitmap not an width . could you please suggest me on this ?

Comment: use one image image view and put padding and margin.

Comment: you can see in this project https://github.com/vishal105/Resources-master

Comment: what is one image image view ?

Comment: can we add space to the image on both the sides and i tried this code.
<item android:gravity="center" android:right="40dp" android:left="40dp" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>